# Why does the tooltip for Convert.ToDateTime() say that it always throws?

Tags: c#, tooltip, .net

The tooltip displayed for `Convert.ToDateTime()` says that it always throws System.InvalidCastException. Why?

Comment: What method? Could you show some code?

Comment: Is this a rant or a question? You did not post any code.

Comment: Post a small code snippet which throws an exception for you when you think it shouldn’t, and we’ll explain why. The way you posed the question here makes no sense.

Comment: right is usually almost always wrong - just depends on which side you are looking from!! ;-)

Comment: are you able to understand what are you asking though? ?? :)

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please ask about the real thing you’re actually talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot cast something like a `short` (or `bool` or various other datatypes) to `DateTime`, so it makes sense for that to always throw. If, however, you try to convert something that could sensibly be converted to a `DateTime`, then it doesn’t:

[image: example screenshot showing the tooltip for two of the Convert.ToDateTime() overloads]

Comment: +1 for finding it.  Makes a person wonder why the overload is provided if it only throws an exception. Seems unreasonable.

Comment: @jdk: My guess is because it prevents boxing. If the overload wasn’t there, then `ToDateTime(object)` would take over and throw the same exception. Even if `ToDateTime(object)` were changed to `ToDateTime(IConvertible)`, which apparently it requires, it would still take over because all the primitive types implement that interface...

Comment: @jdk: Out of curiosity, would you explain to me how you discovered my answer so quickly? I don’t think the site sends out e-mails so soon, and nobody favourited this question, so what did you do? Did you keep reloading this page or something? Or did you and another user just happen to independently stumble upon my answer 8 minutes after it was posted?

Comment: Just saw the question float by as a new one and thought it looked interesting. At one point you had two different answers being developed.

Comment: Yeah, I deleted the other one because it’s obsolete now.